# Installing python3 in Linux when python2 is native

Tags: python, linux

I'm trying to get python3 working and all setup while keeping the python2 libraries in tact (system dependencies and all that).

I've installed Python3.3 (compiled, etc..) and its in /usr/bin/Python3 side by side with /usr/bin/Python2.x

Entering 'python' will take me to a 2.6 IDE and 'python3' or 'python3.3' does nothing. I'm just a little confused, I'm not sure why this isn't working at the moment.

I can actually call it with /usr/bin/python3/bin/python3 and it works. This doesn't look too pretty though, what should I do here?

```
$ pwd
/usr/bin/python3/bin


$ ls
2to3      idle3.3   python3           python3.3m         pyvenv
2to3-3.3  pydoc3    python3.3         python3.3m-config  pyvenv-3.3
idle3     pydoc3.3  python3.3-config  python3-config



$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 2.6.34.7-56.40.amzn1.i686 (mockbuild@build-31003.build) (gcc version 4.4.4 20100525 (Red Hat 4.4.4-5) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Fri Oct 22 18:48:33 UTC 2010
```

Comment: You can put a simlink to `/usr/bin/python3/bin/python3` somewhere on your `$PATH`. Not sure how you installed it and if it should be already available. It usually is.

Comment: You could add the path as an alias to (for example) `python3` in `.bash_profile` (`function python3 { /usr/bin/python3/bin/python3 $1 }`). On OSX I have them both prefixed as; `alias py2='python'` and `
alias py3='python3'`.

Comment: and this binary actually lies under `/usr/bin/python3/bin/python`? Strange dirname... normally, under `/usr/bin` there are only files, no directories, and they a re all supposed to be called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing that comes to mind is that python3 didn't automatically export its path. I think that adding

```
export PATH="/usr/bin/python3/bin:$PATH"
```

to .bash_profile or .bashrc and restarting terminal could do the trick.

Comment: This is done by default if you install Python with the package from the official website :)